# How to deploy web apps on a host

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have recently bought a UNIX host on [Network Solutions](http://networksolutions.com).
I also have made a test dynamic web project in eclipse.

Here's how my folders are arranged:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKMZJ.png]

This is how it looks when I right click my JSP file in eclipse and run it on my Tomcat server locally:

[image: perfect]

But when I export it as a `War` and upload it to my server and run it, I get a blank page. This is how I uploaded it.

Now I try and do it via FTP into my `jserv-app` folder and it prints out the JSP literally and I have to access it by going into `webdir.com/jserv-apps/WebTest/index.jsp`

This is how my `web.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>WebTest</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The rest of the JSP code is just a body with a couple of `<% %>` tags in it.

I also called Network Solutions before I bought it, asking if they support java-hosting with the package I wanted to buy. And they said yes.

I also found it weird that it was `jserv-apps` instead of `webapps`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should talk with your host again. This is most likely an issue with either you uploading your files to the wrong location, or the host not having enabled the processing of your jsp files.

Comment: if you check the uploaded war do you see a folder with the name of your war file? i.e: did tomcat extracted and deployed the war file? if yes, i think the location is correct, it could be some other issue

Comment: Alright so i just ended up cancelling my networksolutions account and signed up to jvmhost.com let me see how this goes